# IllegalAccessError: tried to access class while building Android with ANT

Tags: java, android, ant

We are building our android application with **ANT**. After upgrading to the latest **SDK tools (Rev 21)** and **platform tools (Rev 16)** along with setting the **android:targetSdkVersion="17"** in manifest.xml, our ant build fails with **IllegalAccessError**.

Strangely a double *ant release* succedes:

- *ant clean* -> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
- *ant release* - > BUILD FAILED
- *ant release* - > **BUILD SUCCESSFUL**

While obviously what we actually want to do does not:

- *ant clean release* - > BUILD FAILED

I already regenerated the build.xml with *android update project -p .* resulting in the same beaviour.

See ANT Output below:

```
release:

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

BUILD FAILED
/home/me/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:645: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/me/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:683: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.common.base.Platform from class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.precomputed(CharMatcher.java:684)
    at com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.<clinit>(CharMatcher.java:63)
    at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:129)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SymbolWriter.write(SymbolWriter.java:51)
    at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:711)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Many Thanks and kind regards from snowy Central Europe

Comment: I discovered that having a dependency library project like android-support-v7-appcompat is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone when stumbling over this error:

I had the same issue, the reason were duplicated JARs in Ant's classpath. In my case, checkstyle-5.6-all.jar was added to the ANT_HOME\lib folder which contained the above mentioned classes, that caused some errors due to duplicate classes and access between them.

In this case, I suggest adding a local classpath variable for the Ant target which uses this library and keep the ANT_HOME\lib as clean as possible.

Comment: It is not only `ANT_HOME/lib` that can be the problem. In my case it was `${user.home}/.ant/lib` that had the same jar with two versions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and after many hours solved it. 
Just use latest ANT (but not the one which is coming with Jenkins)
it seems that apache-ant-1.8.4 has some issues. 
but after downloading the latest **apache-ant-1.9.1** ant was able to build the project with library-project successfully

system's config where working ant build with library projects:

```
>ANT: 1.9.1
>Android SDK - 22 rev
>java 1.6.0_38
```

Comment: Are you sure that updating Ant solved your problem?
I updated to "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 14 2013" and I still have the same issue.